# Can I use restarting docker instead restarting app in container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I run app in Docker container. I didn't bundle the app's code into image, but using `-v` to map the code into container in order to upgrade the code more conveniently.

I used to use pm2 to manage the process, and when I upgrade the code, I use `docker exec -it app bash` to go into the container and run `pm2 restart`.

But now I didn't use pm2 any more, just run `node app.js`. When I upgraded the code and need to restart the app, I run `docker restart` to restart the container directly.

If there is any side effect of docker restart? Or is there a better way to restart a node app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a docker restart will just restart the node process in your container, not much. So there's no side effect.

Comment: Is the effect of docker restart similar to docker run? I mean, keep all flags and command I used when I ran docker run.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The restart will just restart the process. It doesn't actually remove the container. The container ID and all the arguments and flags will be the same.